# How can I get the name of a Pyspark dataframe as a string?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have eight Pyspark dataframes with names such as "store", "inventory", and "storage".

I need to create views for each one but in order to streamline, instead of saying

```
store.createOrReplaceTempView('store_view') etc.
```

Is it possible to iterate through a list of dataframes and create a view? For example:

```
df_list = ["store", "inventory", "storage"]

for d in df_list:
    x = "convert dataframe d to a string"
    d.createOrReplaceTempView(x)
```

How can I assign the dataframe name as a string to x?

I suppose you could do the opposite - have a list of strings but then how to get the dataframe from that?

Comment: create simple mapping and use it in for loop

Comment: This is approaching [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) territory.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilise dictionaries for this purpose. Wherein the key would represent the dataframe name and value will be equivalent to the dataframe itself

#### Example

```
in_hash = {
  'store':store,
  'inventory':inventory,
  'storage':storage
}

for name in in_hash:
    in_hash[name].createOrReplaceTempView(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a temporary view of a PySpark DataFrame you can exploit the globals()[] function to dynamically retrieve the corresponding DataFrame object from the global symbol table, searching by name.

```
df_list = ["store", "inventory", "storage"]

for d in df_list:
    df = globals()[d]
    df.createOrReplaceTempView(d)
```